# Looking for more understanding on the replace method

Tags: javascript, regex

I used this as a solution for a coderbyte exercise (longest word) I more or less read every line until I fully comprehended it and then copied it in I'm still not exactly sure how it works. The code is supposed to find the longest word in a sentence.

```
function LongestWord(sen) { 
  //this splits the string(sentence) into an array of words
  var sentence = sen.split(" ");
  var word = "";
  var len = 0;
  // code goes here  
  //this loops through the words split() from the sentence
  for(var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
  /*this part I don't fully understand if I'm right it replaces any letter a-z 
  regardless of case to ""  */
    var strip = sentence[i].replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "");

    if (strip.length > len) {
      word = strip;
      len = strip.length;
    }
  }
  return word; 

}
```

It is mainly the var strip section I'm not understanding. What happens when I call the replace method on sentence[i] and what is the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `var strip = sentence[i].replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "");` will remove all characters that are not a letter.

`[a-zA-Z]` is a character class that contains all letters

`[^a-zA-Z]` is the negation of the precedent character class

`g` if for a global research (i.e. everywhere in the string)

Answer (score 0):

```
/[^a-zA-Z]/
```

if at start of line there is a to z (small) A to Z (capital) found delete those characters

Comment: Actually, no, the `^` at the beginning of the character class means: _"negate this character class"_ - i.e. `/[^a-zA-Z]/` matches one character that is NOT alphabetic anywhere in the string.